# Custom css for custom block/phtml.

Tags: blocks, css, custom, frontend, phtml

Where should I put the custom .css file for my custom block/phtml.

When I want to customize the display of my block then I have to create a custom .css for that. But where do I have to put that .css file and how do I have to call it so my block would know to use that .css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Put your `custom.css` in: `skin/frontend/{package}/{theme}/css/custom.css`

2) Put this piece of code in `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout/local.xml`

```
<your_layout_handle> //Where you want to display your custom.css
   <reference name="head"> 
      <action method="addItem">
        <type>skin_css</type>
        <name>css/custom.css</name>
      </action>
   </reference>
</your_layout_handle>
```

If you display your block in different pages, put this one:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default translate="label" module="page">
      <reference name="head">
          ...
          <action method="addItem"> //add
            <type>skin_css</type> //add
            <name>css/custom.css</name> //add
          </action> //add
      </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

**EDIT:**

What does `<reference name="head">` mean ?

`head` is a block that is located between these tags`<head>...</head>` and it is a block of type `page/html_head` who contains some methods like:

```
public function addCss($name, $params = "")
    {
        $this->addItem('skin_css', $name, $params);
        return $this;
    }

public function addJs($name, $params = "")
    {
        $this->addItem('js', $name, $params);
        return $this;
    }

public function addItem($type, $name, $params=null, $if=null, $cond=null)
    {
        if ($type==='skin_css' && empty($params)) {
            $params = 'media="all"';
        }
        $this->_data['items'][$type.'/'.$name] = array(
            'type'   => $type,
            'name'   => $name,
            'params' => $params,
            'if'     => $if,
            'cond'   => $cond,
       );
        return $this;
    }

public function addLinkRel($rel, $href)
    {
        $this->addItem('link_rel', $href, 'rel="' . $rel . '"');
        return $this;
    }

...
```

> Path: app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php

Comment: And what if I don't have a local.xml?

Comment: Ok got it! Had to create it myself.

Comment: Yes, you create it.

Comment: What does refererence name = head exactly mean, or what does it determine?

Comment: Look my update please