# Have a option to enable/disable the module. I need to load admin page css when my module is enabled. No need to load css while module is disable

Tags: magento2, module, adminhtml, css, default.xml

I write css in path
**app/code/my/module/view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="My_Module::css/menuformat.css"/> 
    </head>
</page>
```

Above code apply `menuformat.css` to all the admin pages whether my module is enabled or not

I am replacing

```
<css ifconfig="My_Module/general/enabled" src="My_Module::css/menuformat.css"/>
```

It returns error

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'css', attribute 'ifconfig': The attribute 'ifconfig' is not allowed.
```

How can i write?. I need css only active when my module is enable otherwise no need .

I am using magento 2.2

I have a option to enable and disable the module . while click enable/disable button it reflects core_config_data table . Based on the table data i need to load the css . If enable load , disable no need to load the css.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom css for custom block/phtml.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176447/custom-css-for-custom-block-phtml)

Comment: @SukumarGorai , i need to load the css based on core_config_data table record. Above code is work for me . but i need to stop css when path  "My_Module/general/enabled" is 0 in core_config_data table. so i try "ifconfig" attributes but it is not accepted. I need to stop the css while path "My_Module/general/enabled" is 0 in core_config_data table. I need to any alternate way to stop the css loading.

Comment: You can check my answer. I think it should help you!

Answer (score 3):

Create a module with name **STech_Css** by following below steps:

**Step 1:**
Create **registration.php** under:

> app/code/STech/Css/registration.php

with content:

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'STech_Css',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Step 2:**
Create **module.xml** under:

> app/code/STech/Css/etc/module.xml

with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="STech_Css" setup_version="0.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
             <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
            <module name="Magento_Quote"/>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
            <module name="Magento_Cms"/>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Step 3:**
Create **system.xml** under:

> app/code/STech/Css/etc/adminhtml/system.xml

with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <tab id="stech_css" translate="label" sortOrder="10">
            <label>STech</label>
        </tab>
        <section id="css" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <class>separator-top</class>
            <label>CSS</label>
            <tab>stech_css</tab>
            <resource>STech_Css::css_config</resource>
            <group id="general" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>General Configuration</label>
                <field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Module Enable</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

**Step 4:**
Create **events.xml** under:

> app/code/STech/Css/etc/frontend/events.xml

with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_load_before">
        <observer name="stech_css_layout_render" instance="STech\Css\Observer\LayoutRender" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**Step 5:**
Create **LayoutRender.php** under:

> app/code/STech/Css/Observer/LayoutRender.php

with content:

```
<?php
namespace STech\Css\Observer;

class LayoutRender implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    const STECH_CSS_ENABLE = 'css/general/enable';

    private $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $enable = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(self::STECH_CSS_ENABLE, \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
        if($enable){
            $observer->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addUpdate($this->getXmlCode());
        }
        return $observer;
    }

    private function getXmlCode()
    {
        return '<head>
                    <css src="STech_Css::css/stech_custom.css"/> 
                </head>';
    }
}
```

**Step 6:**
Create **stech_custom.css** under:

> app/code/STech/Css/view/frontend/web/css/stech_custom.css

And css according to your requirement.

Flush the cache and run setup:upgrade, setup:di:compile and static:content:deploy.

Hope this helps!

Comment: This really does look like the only way to gracefully check for this. I really doubt many module developers will be happy to go to this extent to ensure the else-where site performance when disabling their module.

Answer (score 1):

No need of add `ifconfig` attribute in css tag. Just use this code and setup upgrade module & deploy once.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="My_Module::css/menuformat.css"/> 
    </head>
</page>
```

> php bin/magento s:up
>
> php bin/magento s:s:d or php bin/magento s:s:d -f

Comment: Fine @RohanHapani , But this is always active. i can disable and enable the module. At the time of disable also this css is active in all admin pages

Comment: I need css is active only when the module is enabled

Comment: Please check your module entry enable disable from app/etc/config.php file. Set your module entry to '0' and flush cache and remove generated.

Comment: My module is always enabled in app/etc/config.php file . It changes only in core_config_data table only

Comment: While click the enable/disable button it does not reflect in   app/etc/config.php file . Only reflect in core_config_data table

Comment: "Set your module entry to '0' and flush cache and remove generated." I can enabled and disabled the module at any time while working. It is possible to using core_config_data record to stop the css loading while plugin is diabled

Comment: @RohanHapani When the module is enabled/disabled at a store level, not site wide.