# Add css to a block Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.7, css, static-block, cms-block

In Magento 2, there is a box to place custom CSS to any block. 
[image]

However, I don't see that as an option in Magento 1
[image]

How do I add custom CSS to a block in Magento 1?

Edit for possible dupe:
I want to know how to just add some css to a block, is there not a way to just do that in Magento 1? Do I have to create a custom css and layout class for every block? If that is the case, can I have someone explain a little more clearly how to do this?

Edit for comments:
It won't save an in file style block
[image]
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom css for custom block/phtml.](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/176447/custom-css-for-custom-block-phtml)

Comment: do not use magento interface for css updates, create custom css file with custom path and keep all your changes.

Comment: I looked at that question but I don't really understand the answer

Comment: Why does the interface exist if I'm not suppose to use it?

Comment: You can directly add css using `<style>` tag

Comment: I tried that, when I saved the code, magento deleted it. i'll add some screen shots to show what Im talking about

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly same as M2 but you can do it via Design tab > Layout as XML

So edit CMS page, add XML entry to Lauout as XML. Make sure your js and css is in place and you have following options.

https://www.rowanburgess.co.uk/add-css-javascript-files-cms-pages-magento/

To add a CSS file residing in the skin CSS folder

```
<default>
   <reference name="head">
      <action method="addCss">
         <stylesheet>css/custom.css</stylesheet>
      </action>
   </reference>
</default>
```

To add a Javascript file residing in the skin JS folder

```xml
<default>
   <reference name="head">
      <action method="addItem">
         <type>skin_js</type>
         <name>js/custom.js</name>
         <params/>
      </action>
   </reference>
</default>
```

To add a Javascript file residing in the {magentoroot}/js folder

```xml
<default>
   <reference name="head">
      <action method="addJs">
         <script>custom.js</script>
      </action>
   </reference>
</default>
```

For blocks you will need extension

Someone posted this online

https://github.com/progammer-rkt/magento-js-css-for-static-blocks

Cant say for certain it works